# What is the correct MIME Type for JSON?

Tags: json

I am having problems converting the JSON string in Chrome.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: #  JSON

`application/json`

#  JSONP 

`application/javascript`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The MIME media type for JSON text is 
`application/json`

Hope this helps